# eBay. Is there any reason for not passing the Item.PostalCode field in the AddFixedPriceItem/AddItem requests?

Tags: ebay-api

Despite the eBay recommendation
https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/features-guide/default.html#development/Listing-AnItem.html#ItemLocation, is there any reason for not passing the Item.PostalCode field in eBay - AddFixedPriceItem/AddItem requests?

API
https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/AddFixedPriceItem.html#Request.Item.PostalCode

Comment: It is entirely possible to pass the postal code when calling AddItem. Are you asking why this field is optional?

Comment: Yes, I can safely not to pass the field. So the question is in the bound of some specific business logic.